# Receive events when QCustomContextMenu is open

Tags: qt, contextmenu, qwidget

I have an issue capturing the key and mouse events. I have a class which inherits QGLWidget. I invoke a context menu QCustomContextMenu by setting the context menu policy of the widget. As the context menu is open, I am unable to capture the mouse and key events. I will need the events to be captured even when the context menu is open.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i believe you have heard about the installEventFilter.

you have to install the event filter for the object you want events to be received (e.g Contextmenu).

install event filter, and create event filter method to handle event in a way you want.